# Set input value with billing address prefix in html file

Tags: magento2, javascript, html, input

In html file, i could show the billing address prefix with `text: currentBillingAddress().prefix`. But when i tried to give data-bind to input, it become `<input type="hidden" id="test2" data-bind="text: currentBillingAddress().prefix"/>Prefix</input>`.

How can i set the value of input to billing address prefix? I already tried `<input type="hidden" id="test2" input="text: currentBillingAddress().prefix"/>` but it's not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use **`data-bind:value`** property for set value in input tag.

```
<input type="hidden" id="test2" data-bind="value: currentBillingAddress().prefix"/>Prefix</input>
```